# How to get javascript date from gijgo/datepicker?

Tags: javascript, datepicker

In my laravel 5.7/ blade / jQuery 3 / Bootstrap 4.1 app
I use 2 datepickers from here https://gijgo.com/datepicker/configuration and setting format property :

```
$('#check_in_datepicker').datepicker({            // uiLibrary: 'bootstrap',
    uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
    iconsLibrary: 'fontawesome',
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    format: 'dd mmmm, yyyy'
});
```

and I got that my date is shown as ‘25 January, 2019’, that is what I expected, but I need to read this value in javascript format as I need :
1) to check on client that 1st date is less then 2nd date
2) to save selected data in mysql in "YYYY-MM-DD" format

If this gijgo/datepicker/ has possibility(I did not find) to convert date on client or Javascript has some good tools to do it ?

$('#check_in_datepicker').val()
returns string text as ‘25 January, 2019’...

Thanks!

Comment: You can convert the string to a Date object and then format it however you want after that. `const date = new Date('25 January 2019')` and then from there you can do whatever you need to with it. Look up the documentation on the Date object to see exactly how you can format it to.  [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: You have convert the date(YYY-mm-DD) into (dd-mm-YYYY) is your question?